# Insert user ID value into messages table where user division = division.divisionid

Tags: php, mysql, insert, while-loop

How do I insert a table entry in my messages table for each user.ID where the users.MM_Division = division.divisionid

I want to insert the user ID value in the messages.messagesuserid

I think I need a while loop but I'm not sure how I implement it when dealing with a insert query.

Currently, only 1 message row is inserted into the messages table on the messageuserid value posts as NULL

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
session_start();

$colname_division = "-1";
if ((isset($_GET['divisionid'])) && ($_GET['divisionid'] != "")) {
      $colname_division = $_GET['divisionid'];

mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
$query_users = sprintf("SELECT users.*, division.* FROM users INNER JOIN division ON division.divisionid = users.MM_Division WHERE divisionid = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_users, "int"));
$users = mysql_query($query_users, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($users);
$totalRows_users = mysql_num_rows($users);


// MESSAGE USERS DIVISION ARCHIVED
    $messageinsertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO messages (message, messageuserid) VALUES ('The division " . $row_division['division'] . " has been archived by " . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . " please select a new division', '" . $row_users['ID'] . "')",GetSQLValueString($_GET['divisionid'], "int")); 
    mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
    $Result4 = mysql_query($messageinsertSQL, $connect) or die(mysql_error());


// REDIRECT
    $updateGoTo = "../divisions.php";
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
            $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
    header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));

    mysql_free_result($division);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap that `message users division archived` part with:

```
while (($row_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)) !== false) {
 $messageInsert = ...
 [...]
}
```

Then you need to remove `$row_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)` used earlier.

BTW, I'm not sure if some columns won't get overwritten if they have the same names (from users and divisions) in `$query_users =` line. 
Besides, that line has wrong parameter `$colname_users` in `GetSQLValueString()` function (shouldn't it be `$colname_division`? Or do you declare it somewhere else?).